# It's time for Clean Up Week!

Tags: discussion, cleanup

Following on from [Bruno's post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2853/swag-for-the-cleanup-team) I've just added a new event to the clean up system: [Clean Up Week 1](http://cleanup.thepcspy.com/leaderboard/2/)

- **When?!** The event lasts 7 days, starting at 00:00 on the 30th of March running through the end of the 5th April. Times are in UTC so adjust accordingly.
- **Who?!** The event is open to all users.
- **"But I'm way behind! That's not fair!"** Don't worry, the scores for the event will be separate from the ongoing leaderboard so everybody has an equal chance.
- **PRIZES!** We have three prizes for this. The two runners up will get a lovely Ubuntu mug and mouse. The winner gets an epic [Ubuntu wall light](http://www.etsy.com/listing/75747073/ubuntu-linux-logo-wall-light-computer).
- **Scores aren't everything.** They count for a lot but we're going to keep a close eye on things and will be factoring in things like teamwork to help us decide who wins. This means if you blindly flag *everything* for closure, you're probably not going to win.

Any questions?

Comment: What do we do when people aggressively pursue things that might not need to be closed?

Comment: **Hint:** For the teamwork part 'o things, [using chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/206/ubuntu-regulators) can be useful (since not everyone knows about chat!)

Comment: Don't blind flag things, editing, answering and team work is the key, if your flags are returning _declined_ that will be the hint you are doing something wrong! Moderators will keep a close eye on all the action happening around!

Comment: I <3 you guys. If my graphics card works and other variables are right.. I *will* try to make this site a better placwe

Comment: how to do it? it requires an open id :o ,why i cant use ask ubuntu account or fb account for it?

Comment: @tachyons Most people here have an OpenID of some sort (Launchpad provides one, for instance) and it made development much easier. In time the aim is to use the Stack Exchange authentication but that isn't there yet. Edit: Oh and you can use your Stack Exchange as an OpenID, see the FAQ on: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2651/ask-ubuntu-clean-up

Comment: Thanks, Jokerdino helped me to do it :)

Comment: Can we do this again!

Comment: Clean-up week anyone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Cleanup Week (April 2012)** has been a fantastic effort by the whole Ask Ubuntu community.

That last word is important - *community* - without our fantastic users, this site would not be as great as it has become.

---

First - the major special thanks has to go to @Oli - without Oli, this cleanup week would simply have never happened.  The website & cleanup routines were invaluable.

---

Your community moderators have been keeping a close eye on proceedings.  The common consensus was *wow* - we just could not believe the commitment of numerous people to the cleanup effort.

At our low point, Ask Ubuntu was at 72% answered rate.  Second to last of all the Stack Exchange sites.

However, with the help of many - and this week in particular, we have reached the dizzying heights of 84.7% answered rate.  That puts us up to the number 2 of the top 5 (in terms of size) of the [Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questions).

We were looking for not only those questions that could and should be closed but more importantly, improving both questions and answers, upvoting great answers and creating new great answers to almost forgotten questions.

It has been hard … and if we had more we would have given more prizes.

In life there are winners and losers - but on this occasion we consider all the entrants as winners.

Our runners up for Cleanup Week (April 2012) are

- Amith KK
- Bodhi.zazen

For both dedication, bringing various people together - and for virtually living in the regulators room...

Drum Roll....

Our grand prize winner is....

## BlueXrider

postscript...

Well done all and many thanks - **but we must just say, we cannot stop now.**

We'll be contacting all the winners shortly - so look out for your email!

Comment: It was a great TEAM effort, thanks for all who helped.

Comment: Congrats to BlueXrider, well done.

Comment: Congrats to BlueXrider ,Amith KK and Bodhi.zazen

Comment: Well done BlueXrider - you've had an outstanding week and set a very high benchmark for others!! to Amith and bodhi congrats on trying to keep up with him!!